# Modify Row Data of the table in BIRT

Tags: javascript, event-handling, birt

I want to change the data present in the row of the table which I used for grouping purpose in the BIRT. I know how to retrieve the value but I want to change the rendering value, precisely I want to transform the string. I checked an example on official page [here](https://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/reportScripting.php):

```
if (this.getRowData().getExpressionValue(3) > 100)
    this.getStyle().backgroundColor="red";//This will only change the row instance
```

This is helpful to change the style of the text but I want to change the text rather than the style

```
var t = this.getRowData().getExpressionValue("row[colname]");
t= t.toUpperCase();  //any string transformation
this.valueExpr = t;  //this is not working
```

So how to assign new string to the row. I write this script at onRender event of the row. But it is not working. Any Idea?

Comment: This question is also posted at actuate  http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/34254-modify-row-data-of-the-table-in-birt/

Comment: Yes, I was the one who asks the same question there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this in the onRender event of a **data** element (**not** on the row element):

```
var newval=this.getValue().toString().toUpperCase();
this.setDisplayValue(newval);
```

Comment: Problem Solved.. I should try out this thing at first place. Perfectly worked. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I am not exactly sure what your desired end result is, but what I usually do when I want to modify a value; is create a computed column.

In this example I have a numerical values in the column (*seAssignment*) and I want to display a string value that is not not in the database.  I can than add this to my table just like any existing data column includig using it to group on.

- Open the data set in Outline
- Click on Computed Column
- New
- Give it a name & Data Type (string)

Expression

```
if (row["seAssignment"] ==0){
"In use"
}else if (row["seAssignment"] ==1){
"In stock"
}else if (row["seAssignment"] ==2){
"Retired (or consumed)"
}else if (row["seAssignment"] ==3){
"Awaiting receipt"
}else if (row["seAssignment"] ==4){
"Return for maintenance"
}else if (row["seAssignment"] ==5){
"Return to supplier"
}else if (row["seAssignment"] ==6){
"Missing"
}else { 
"Undefined"}
```

Comment: Yes, we can achieve it using Computed columns but my template is little complicated and lots of things are present so I can't use it but yes it is a good option. Dominique's answer works for me.

Comment: IMO using a computed column or a binding with an expression is much cleaner than changing the value in the onRender event.